# Customize Redirection in Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-authentication

I want to customize Laravel Auth. I want to distinguish between admins and users. In the default users table, I added column role with two options: admin and user. According to the manual, I'm defining `redirectTo` method.

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
            return 'admin/home';
        } else {
            return '/main';
        }
    }

    protected function show_admin_homepage()
    {
        return view('auth.admin_h');
    }

    protected function show_user_homepage()
    {
        return view('auth.user_h');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('main', 'Auth\LoginController@show_user_homepage')->name('show_user_homepage');
Route::get('admin/home', 'Auth\LoginController@show_admin_homepage')->name('show_admin_homepage');
```

The problem is that when I'm logging as a user or as admin, I'm always redirecting to default laravel home view. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The default Login Controller is using **AuthenticatesUsers** trait. In the trait, there is a protected method defined named **authenticated** override it in the Login Controller.

Below is an implementation of the **authenticated** method

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    if($user->role == 'admin')
    {
        return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
    else if($user->role == 'user')
    {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was middleware. Methods displaying admin and user homepages were defined in LoginController where guest middleware is used. by default. For these method auth middleware should be aplied. Thank you all for engagement.

Answer (score 1):

You should change redirection in the `handle` method of the `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` file which locate in the `App/Http/Middleware`

It method looks like following;

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I would like to distinguish admins and users...*

Instead of trying to re-create the wheel and tinkering with the Auth, why not just use something that's already built and easy to use?

[Spatie/Laravel-Permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) can help you out a ton here.

For example, to create an 'admin' role, you would just do the following:

```
$role = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
```

Then give it some permissions:

```
$permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'super power']);
$role->givePermissionTo($permission);
```

And assign a role to a User model in your controller

```
$user->assignRole('admin');
```

From there you can query whether or not a user has a particular role, either in your controller:

```
if( $user->hasRole('admin') )
{
    // The user has the admin role 
    return view('admin-page');

} else {
    // This is a generic user 
    return view('main');

}
```

**OR** in your blade

```
@role('admin')
    I took the red pill!
@else 
    I took the blue pill.. 
@endrole
```

I suggest this because it's scalable and easy to integrate into your project. As your project continues to grow, if you need to add new permissions to a role it's a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks @UkraineInTheMembrane. I heard about this package. I just want to tinker. It turned out that I don't understand manual here.